# Pattern matching of a url path

Tags: java, regex, split, pattern-matching

I have the below urls which I need to parse:

```
a) https://url:port/abc
b) https://url:port/abc/{uid}
c) https://url:port/abc/{uid}/def
```

To figure out the type of the url (a, b or c), I am doing:

```
Pattern a = Pattern.compile(".*\\/abc$");
Pattern b = ??
Pattern c = Pattern.compile(".*\\/abc\\/(.*?)\\/def$");
```

Patterns **a** and **c** are working fine. Though I am not sure what pattern can I use so that the exact url of type **b** can be matched, without having to rely on order of the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
 .*\\/abc\\/([^\\/]*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EJlBFL/2)

Nor the part after the slash: `([^\\/]*)$` it allows any number of characters that are not slashes, therefore it allows `uid` but not another part of the path.

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by bit slashes?

Comment: "not slashes" - veeeery weird typo :)